# Comparing values in two columns of two different Splunk searches

Tags: comparison, splunk

I am new to splunk and facing an issue in comparing values in two columns of two different queries.

**Query 1**

```
index="abc_ndx" source="*/jkdhgsdjk.log" call_id="**" A_to="**" A_from="**" | transaction call_id keepevicted=true | search "xyz event:" | table _time, call_id, A_from, A_to | rename call_id as Call_id, A_from as From, A_to as To
```

**Query 2**

```
index="abc_ndx" source="*/ jkdhgsdjk.log" call_id="**" B_to="**" B_from="**" | transaction call_id keepevicted=true | search " xyz event:"| table _time, call_id, B_from, B_to | rename call_id as Call_id, B_from as From, B_to as To
```

These are my two different queries. I want to compare each values in `A_from` column with each values in `B_from` column and if the value matches, then display the those values of `A_from`.

Is it possible?

I have run the two queries separately and exported the results of each into csv and used `vlookup` function. But the problem is there is a ***limit of max 10000 rows*** of data which can be exported and so I miss out lots of data as my data search has more than 10000 records. 
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't got any data to test this on at the moment, however, the following should point you in the right direction.

When you have the table for the first query sorted out, you should 'pipe' the search string to an `appendcols` command with your second search string. This command will allow you to run a subsearch and "import" a columns into you base search.

Once you have the two columns in the same table. You can use the `eval` command to create a new field which compares the two values and assigns a value as you desire.

Hope this helps.

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0.2/SearchReference/Appendcols
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Eval

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why there is a need to keep this as two separate queries.  Everything is coming from the same sourcetype, and is using almost identical data.  So I would do something like the following:

```
index="abc_ndx" source="*/jkdhgsdjk.log" call_id="**" (A_to="**" A_from="**") OR (B_to="**" B_from="**") 
| transaction call_id keepevicted=true 
| search "xyz event:" 
| eval to=if(A_from == B_from, A_from, "no_match")
| table _time, call_id, to
```

This grabs all events from your specified sourcetype and index, which have a call_id, and either A_to and A_from or B_to and B_from.  Then it transactions all of that, lets you filter based on the "xyz event:" (Whatever that is)

Then it creates a new field called 'to' which shows A_from when A_from == B_from, otherwise it shows "no_match"  (Placeholder since you didn't specify what should be done when they don't match)

There is also a way to potentially tackle this without using transactions.  Although without more details into the underlying data, I can't say for sure.  The basic idea is that if you have a common field (call_id in this case) you can just use stats to collect values associated with that field instead of an expensive transaction command.

For example:

```
index="abc_ndx" index="abc_ndx" source="*/jkdhgsdjk.log" call_id="**"
| stats last(_time) as earliest_time first(A_to) as A_to first(A_from) as A_from first(B_to) as B_to first(B_from) as B_from by call_id
```

Using first() or last() doesn't actually matter if there is only one value per call_id.  (You can even use min() max() avg() and you'll get the same thing)  Perhaps this will help you get to the output you need more easily.